# Adjusting the labelSize according to text size in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've programatically added a Label to a UIView. However I can't seem to make it auto size according to the text inside the Label. I've tried to use this extension, but I'm not sure how to use it properly

```
extension UILabel {
    func resizeHeightToFit(heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font]
        numberOfLines = 0
        lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        let rect = text!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        heightConstraint.constant = rect.height
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

then I've tried this:

```
titleLabel?.resizeHeightToFit(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: titleLabel!.frame.height))
```

but it returns error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sizeToFit()`:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Text"
label.sizeToFit()
print(label.frame) // "(0.0, 0.0, 32.5, 20.5)"
label.text = "Text that is pretty long this time"
label.sizeToFit()
print(label.frame) // "(0.0, 0.0, 241.5, 20.5)"
```